# Solving computing time problem when grid size element increases in flood model?

Tags: dem, resolution, flood, precipitation

I want to create high resolution and high accuracy "area of inundation" map using FLO-2D Model. I have high resolution Digital Elevation Model (DEM) and I must show small topographic details on my maps. To avoid the loss of these details, I need to use small grid size nearly 30 centimeters. If I select small grid size, grid number increases. So, my insufficient computer doesn't solve numerical schema of flood/rainfall modelling.

Do I divide study area some segments?

Or what can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your problem and the nature of the details you want to keep, you might want to :

- Use a channel with cross sections in Flo-2D to have a close approach of the river bed
- Use coarser elements outside this area, if the precision there is less critical.

In Flo-2D, you might also want to check the water depth and increase the roughness if the depth is too low. Check the TIME.out file to find the elements. 
More details about that can be found in the documentation (folder flo-help)